# MySQL daemon command line login hangs

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have MySQL restarted on Ubuntu (Version 16), and the login command hangs for  unknown reasons.

```
   ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-122:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
    [ ok ] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-122:~$
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-122:~$
    ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-122:~$ sudo mysqld -u root -p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are starting a new instance of the server in the foreground ?

```
sudo mysqld -u root -p
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html

If you want to login to your running instance

```
mysql -u root -p
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html